# Switching Letters to characters in an array

Tags: java, arrays, list

I am trying to switch characters with characters stored in an array and my teacher and I are stuck,

An example of this is:

abcdef would switch to zyxwvu

or

hello would switch to svool

Below is a picture of said code and as well as a link

[Picture to code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z70me.png)

[Link to code (If you can access it](https://repl.it/@terminator69851/Activity-33)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will help you to understand the flow :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ****************************************
    // ** Call your function to test them in **
    // ** the main function here.            **
    // ****************************************

    String msg = "Yes Sir How may I help you ";

    //Alphabet 
    String alpha[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};

    //Alphabet Reversed
    String alpharev[] = {"z", "y", "x", "w", "v", "u", "t", "s", "r", "q", "p", "o", "n", "m", "l", "k", "j", "i", "h", "g", "f", "e", "d", "c", "b", "a"};

    String converted = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++){

      if(msg.charAt(i) >= 'a'){
        converted+=alpharev[msg.charAt(i) - 'a'];
      } else if(msg.charAt(i) >= 'A'){
        converted+=alpharev[msg.charAt(i) - 'A'];
      } else{
        converted+= msg.charAt(i) ;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Message: " + converted);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, now a quick add on to what you sent, If I were to be able to reverse it back svool --> hello how would I do that

Comment: just interchange the value of String alpha[] to String alpharev[]  and viceversa

Comment: //Alphabet 
    String alpha[] = {"z", "y", "x", "w", "v", "u", "t", "s", "r", "q", "p", "o", "n", "m", "l", "k", "j", "i", "h", "g", "f", "e", "d", "c", "b", "a"};

    //Alphabet Reversed
    String alpharev[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};

Comment: I changed the values within the array-like you said Link: https://imgur.com/97AeIs4
what did I do wrong

Comment: Actually dont do anything the above code will work for reverse too...

Comment: svool will be printed as hello.. with above code without any change

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you should change `i >= alpha.length` to `i < msg.length()`, but that doesn't really matter, because what you're doing will not work.

The `msg.replace(...)` call will not change the value of `msg`, but even if it did, the result would not be what you want, because you would change `a` to `z`, then later you would change `z` back to `a`.

Take a step back and re-think what you're trying to do.

---

*Hint:* Use `msg.toCharArray()`, then update the characters in the array, and convert back to `String` when done.

```java
static String switchLetters(String text) {
    char[] chars = Normalizer.normalize(text, Normalizer.Form.NFD).toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        char ch = chars[i];
        if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
            chars[i] = (char) ('z' - (ch - 'a'));
        else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
            chars[i] = (char) ('Z' - (ch - 'A'));
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(switchLetters("abcdef"));
System.out.println(switchLetters("hello"));
System.out.println(switchLetters("Yes Sir How may I help you "));
System.out.println(switchLetters("héllô"));
```

*Output*

```
zyxwvu
svool
Bvh Hri Sld nzb R svok blf 
sv́ool̂
```